# Picasso and Coil inconsistency in image sizing?

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso, coil

The first screenshot is with Picasso, the second one with Coil (both in latest versions). Any idea why is this happening?

Picasso: `fit().centerInside()`

Coil: `scale(Scale.FILL).crossfade(true)` (I tried with FIT also, same results)

ImageView: `adjustViewBounds = true; scaleType = CENTER_INSIDE` with MATCH_PARENT width and constant height in pixels.

[image: Picasso]

[image: Coil]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coil automatically adjusts to the scale type of the `ImageView` so you don't need to configure the scale.

Picasso does not, and Picasso's `.fit().centerInside()` is actually not equivalent to `ImageView`'s `CENTER_INSIDE` but to `FIT_CENTER` (it will enlarge the image so that at least one dimension matches the `ImageView`). There is no equivalent to `CENTER_INSIDE` with Picasso but these are the closest options:

- You can simply remove `.fit().centerInside()` and let the `ImageView` scale down the image if it's larger, but if the image is very large it will consume a lot of memory (and may fail to load if larger than the max texture size of the device).
- You can use `.resize(width, height).centerInside().onlyScaleDown()` after measuring the size of the `ImageView` manually.

If you want Coil to resize the image the same way Picasso does with `.fit().centerInside()`, then just change the scale type of the `ImageView` to `FIT_CENTER`.